# Appcelerator titanium crashes building java files for my android project

Tags: java, android, crash, titanium, appcelerator

My project was compiled successfully 3 weeks ago. I'm avoiding to update appcelerator components because certain modules of my project need that specific version.

I'm not update Java (1.8 131) neither the appcelerator cli or sdk since 3 weeks ago. The SDK version i am using is 6.0.2.

I can't undestand why titanium is showing this errors now in the "building Java source files" stage:

```
[INFO]  Building Java source files: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/javac "-J-Xmx1024M" "-encoding" "utf8" "-bootclasspath" "/home/user/android-sdk/platforms/android-23/android.jar:/home/user/.titanium/mobilesdk/linux/6.0.2.GA/android/kroll-v8.jar:/home/user/.titanium/mobilesdk/linux/6.0.2.GA/android/modules/titanium-analytics.jar:/home/user/.titanium/mobilesdk/linux/6.0.2.GA/android/aps-analytics.jar:/home/user/.titanium/mobilesdk/linux/6.0.2.GA/android/modules/titanium-android.jar:/home/user/.titanium/mobilesdk/linux/6.0.2.GA/android/jaxen-1.1.1.jar:/home/user/.titanium/mobilesdk/linux/6.0.2.GA/android/ti-commons-codec-1.3.jar:/home/user/.titanium/mobilesdk/linux/6.0.2.GA/android/kroll-common.jar:/home/user/.titanium/mobilesdk/linux/6.0.2.GA/android/titanium.jar:/home/user/.titanium/mobilesdk/linux/6.0.2.GA/android/android-support-multidex.jar:/home/user/.titanium/mobilesdk/linux/6.0.2.GA/android/modules/titanium-filesystem.jar:/home/user/.titanium/mobilesdk/linux/6.0.2.GA/android/modules/titanium-app.jar:/home/user/.titanium/mobilesdk/linux/6.0.2.GA/android/modules/titanium-ui.jar:/home/user/.titanium/mobilesdk/linux/6.0.2.GA/android/nineoldandroids-appc-2.4.0.jar:/home/user/.titanium/mobilesdk/linux/6.0.2.GA/android/modules/titanium-media.jar:/home/user/.titanium/mobilesdk/linux/6.0.2.GA/android/modules/titanium-appcompat.jar:/home/user/.titanium/mobilesdk/linux/6.0.2.GA/android/android-support-v4.jar:/home/user/.titanium/mobilesdk/linux/6.0.2.GA/android/android-support-v7-appcompat.jar:/home/user/.titanium/mobilesdk/linux/6.0.2.GA/android/modules/titanium-cardview.jar:/home/user/.titanium/mobilesdk/linux/6.0.2.GA/android/cardview-v7-23.0.1.jar:/home/user/.titanium/mobilesdk/linux/6.0.2.GA/android/modules/titanium-locale.jar:/home/user/.titanium/mobilesdk/linux/6.0.2.GA/android/modules/titanium-network.jar:/home/user/.titanium/mobilesdk/linux/6.0.2.GA/android/modules/titanium-xml.jar:/home/user/.titanium/mobilesdk/linux/6.0.2.GA/android/modules/titanium-map.jar:/home/user/.titanium/mobilesdk/linux/6.0.2.GA/android/modules/titanium-calendar.jar:/home/user/.titanium/mobilesdk/linux/6.0.2.GA/android/modules/titanium-geolocation.jar:/home/user/.titanium/mobilesdk/linux/6.0.2.GA/android/modules/titanium-database.jar:/home/user/.titanium/mobilesdk/linux/6.0.2.GA/android/modules/titanium-accelerometer.jar:/home/user/.titanium/mobilesdk/linux/6.0.2.GA/android/modules/titanium-platform.jar:/home/user/.titanium/mobilesdk/linux/6.0.2.GA/android/modules/titanium-contacts.jar:/home/user/.titanium/mobilesdk/linux/6.0.2.GA/android/modules/titanium-gesture.jar:/home/user/.titanium/mobilesdk/linux/6.0.2.GA/android/modules/titanium-utils.jar:/home/user/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/myproject/modules/android/ti.map/3.1.1/map.jar:/home/user/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/myproject/modules/android/ti.map/3.1.1/lib/google-play-services-gcm+maps.jar:/home/user/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/myproject/modules/android/ti.imagefactory/3.0.0/imagefactory.jar:/home/user/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/myproject/modules/android/ti.goosh/2.0.5/ti.goosh.jar:/home/user/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/myproject/modules/android/ti.goosh/2.0.5/lib/gson.jar:/home/user/.titanium/mobilesdk/linux/6.0.2.GA/android/kroll-apt.jar:/home/user/.titanium/mobilesdk/linux/6.0.2.GA/android/lib/titanium-verify.jar:Manifest.class:R.class:AssetCryptImpl.class:FixioActivity.class:FixioAppInfo.class:FixioApplication.class" "-d" "/home/user/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/myproject/build/android/bin/classes" "-proc:none" "-target" "1.6" "-source" "1.6" "@/home/user/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/myproject/build/android/java-sources.txt"
[ERROR] Failed to compile Java source files:
[ERROR]   
[ERROR] /home/user/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/myproject/build/android/gen/es/myproject/AssetCryptImpl.java:44: error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]             Range range = assets.get(path);
[ERROR]                           ^
[ERROR]   symbol:   variable assets
[ERROR]   location: class AssetCryptImpl
[ERROR] /home/user/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/myproject/build/android/gen/es/myproject/AssetCryptImpl.java:48: error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]             return new String(filterDataInRange(assetsBytes, range.offset, range.length));
[ERROR]                                                 ^
[ERROR]   symbol:   variable assetsBytes
[ERROR]   location: class AssetCryptImpl
[ERROR] Note: /home/user/Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace/myproject/build/android/gen/es/fixio/AssetCryptImpl.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
[ERROR] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
[ERROR] 2 errors
```

Thanks in advance for your help and sorry for my bad English.

UPDATE (2017-07-05):

I found this appcelerator jira with the same problem:
https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-24895

I'm waiting for a official workarround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the problem is version 4.4.0-81 of my linux kernel (Ubuntu 16.04). At the moment, my solution has been to start up with version 4.4.0-79 in order to compile as usually.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried cleaning the project directory before compiling? If you're using studio, just go to Project/Clean in the menu and select your project, or you can use the command line tools (http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Titanium_CLI_Tasks-section-src-38931164_TitaniumCLITasks-CleanYourBuildFolder)

Comment: Yes, I tried it without results. I should have written it in my original question. Sorry.